# Не работает кодировка PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь вывести в тег заголовок на странице в зависимости от урла. Например, если последнее слово в урле shop, то заголовок - Каталог и т.д. Всё меняется, но, если используется кириллица, то вместо слов кракозябры из процентов.

```html
    <?
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $last_arr=explode('/', $url);

    $last = $last_arr[count($last_arr)-1];
    $last2 = $last_arr[count($last_arr)-2];

    if($last === 'shop'){
        $headers = 'Каталог';
      }
    elseif($last2 === 'category'){
        $headers = 'Категории';
    }
      elseif($last2 === 'search'){
   
        $headers = 'Результаты поиска по запросу';
        $headers = $headers.' “'.$last.'“';

      }
    ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: /questions/1237039/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-php - это ссылка на твой вопрос. Это ничего что здесь "кракозябры из процентов"? Возможно, так и должно быть?

Comment: @ипатьев кракозябры не в самой ссылке, а в теге, где должен выводиться послденее слово из урла.

Comment: никто не знает что значит "в теге". Если данная cтрока кодируется,  то *очевидно*,  где-то вызывается urlencode. Спрашивать надо у автора кода, зачем он это делает

Comment: @Ипатьев urlencode такое нигде не указывается  в коде

Comment: если urlencode  нигде не вызывается, значит никаких процентов не выводится

Comment: @Ипатьев как видно на скриншоте, выводится. Даже если я в чистом файле напишу этот код, всё равно кракозябры.

Comment: Если значение берется из REQUEST_URI, то его надо раскодировать

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php